# Rendering a webpage located on device with react native

Tags: webview, react-native, local-storage

I have researched quite a lot and tried to no avail to render a locally located webpage (with dynamic content based off of get vars in the url) to render in a webpage on android and ios with react native. 
Firstly is this even possible?
and if its not possible is there any other cross platform mobile development technologies out there that can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: thanks for your speedy reply.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the way its all generated as its pre-made content but what I do know is that there is xml files and images generated based on the url GET vars that is handled with js. For eg. lang=fr then the js loads 'image-fr.jpg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to load local html into the webview. You can pass the html via `require` to the webview's `source` property. There's an example in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html):

```
render(): ReactElement<any> {
      return (
        <WebView
          style={{
            backgroundColor: BGWASH,
            height: 100,
          }}
          source={require('./helloworld.html')}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
        />
      );
    }
```

You can use the `injectedJavaScript` property to inject javascript containing your arguments in order to make the content dynamic.

```
render(): ReactElement<any> {
          return (
            <WebView
              style={{
                backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                height: 100,
              }}
              source={require('./helloworld.html')}
              scalesPageToFit={true}
              injectedJavaScript="var a = 1;"
            />
          );
        }
```

Comment: 1. If I can get something like this working then does this load any of the js and css dependencies in the index.html? I've read quite a few places that this isn't possible. 
2. I got an example working on the ios simulator with a copy of one of the websites that my company has made, but when we compiled to a device we just got a blank webview. On a few of the questions on this subject around the internet some people said that the only reason it is possible on the computer is because react accesses the files through the computer server. But that its not possible on the device. Is this correct?

Comment: note: I've tried this example and it does work great. Just as soon as i put the css and js in separate files it breaks the app. It just renders what html is in the main file.

Comment: @TheMan68 are the js and css files local or remote?

Comment: All the files are located locally